# RxSwift throttle() to get first element

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I am looking for a way in which the `throttle()` operator gives up the first element in an `Observable` within a given time-interval, rather than the last element.

A similar question has been asked (and answered) in [RxSwift - Debounce/Throttle "inverse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438268/rxswift-debounce-throttle-inverse), but there is an imperfection in those answers that I would like to avoid. That is, in an ideal scenario, the first element emitted in the `Observable` is obtained and any future ones are ignored for the duration of the time-interval. However, when working with `window()` or `timer()`, it is possible that two elements proceed *within* the given time-interval, because the timer happened not to run parallel to the start of the `throttle()` call. Example:

```
|..........|..........|..........|
                    ^   ^
                first   second
```

They fall into different windows and are therefore both accepted by the imperfect solution described in the linked answer.

Ideally, there would be a way to restart the timer as soon as the first element in a window comes in, so that the above example would instead look something like:

```
|..........|.......|..........|
                    ^   ^
                first   second (ignored)
```

Any ideas?

Edit: to be clear, I am not sure how the throttle() variety of RxSwift 3.0-beta1 handles this, but I am looking for a solution for RxSwift 2.x implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, rxSwift 3.0 deals with `throttle()` in exactly the way I desired. It takes an element and then ignores any further elements for x seconds (without having the 'window problem' I alluded to in the question).

For the sake of completeness: `debounce()` still works in accordance with rxSwift's 'old' definition of throttling. That is, it takes the last item in a time-interval.